# Combinatorial proof of an identity on sum of elements in a grid

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

The following problem was motivated by the calculation of the dimension of a particular finite dimensional algebra. Fix a positive integer $n$, and consider an $n \times n$ grid of squares. In the outer layer of squares, place a $1$ in each square; in the second-to-outer layer place a $2$ in each square; and so on. For example, when $n=5$ the grid of squares looks like:

```
1 1 1 1 1
1 2 2 2 1
1 2 3 2 1
1 2 2 2 1
1 1 1 1 1
```

It is not difficult to show that the sum of the elements in such a square is given by $\binom{n+2}{3}$. However, the presence of a binomial coefficient leads me to wonder if there is a *combinatorial* reason/proof for this fact, or at least a method which doesn't resort to simply summing the elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the number in cell counts the # of bricks stacked on that cell. Assume $n$ is odd. Then the lowest layer has $n^2$ bricks, the second lowest layer has $(n-2)^2$ bricks, $\cdots$, and the highest layer has $1$ brick. Therefore, the total number of bricks, or say, the sum of all numbers, is
$$
1^2 + 3^2 + \cdots + (n-2)^2 + n^2 = {n + 2\choose 3}
$$
The case for even $n$ is similar.

Comment: Yup, this is the "right" way to do it. (There's a small typo in your binomial coefficient.)

Comment: @lokodiz Thanks. Edited.